# How to get dropdownlist selected value while I am editing data in detailsView control?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, data-access-layer, detailsview, templatefield

I have one dataAccessLayer.cs which supply edit, delete, update method; one GridView control to show limited data; one DetailsView control to show more details value. 
   When i press select button in gridview and then detailsView fill detail value.
But I create dropdownlist on the codeBehind to show data in detailsView. so far there are no bug
but 
   When I want to edit data in detailView program do not catch dropdownlist value for editing

```
protected void DetailsView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DetailsView1.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Edit)
        {
            DropDownList dropDownList = (DropDownList)DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList2");
            dropDownList.DataSource = ss.DataTableMtd("spGetAllMarkaIdName");
            dropDownList.DataTextField = "Marka_Name";
            dropDownList.DataValueField = "Marka_Name";
            dropDownList.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I find the answer.

```
    protected void DetailsView1_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        ObjectDataSource2.UpdateParameters["MarkaName"].DefaultValue = 
        ((DropDownList)DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList2")).SelectedValue;            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the SelectedValue by using the Value property of dropdown control, It returns the value(text) of selected index ie

```
string value = dropDownList.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: You know detailsView edit button get value automatically! And I don't know where I write    string value=DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();